# C++: OpenMP shared memory protection

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, shared-memory

If I use a shared variable, let's say a double, to calculate some kind of sum along the execution of the program. Would that in anyway be vulnerable to non-stable operations? I mean, would it be possible that more than one core would access this variable in an asynchronous way and cause unstable results?

For example:
this is a global variable:

```
double totalTime = 0;
```

and in each core a command is called:

```
totalTime += elapsedTime;
```

This last operation/statement is executed by taking the value of totalTime, put it the the CPU register, and then do the addition. I can imagine that more than one core would take the same value at the same instant, and then add the new elapsedTime, and then the value stored in totalTime would be overwritten with the wrong value, due to latency. Is that possible? and how can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly this operation is not thread-safe since, as you mentioned yourself, it involves several assembler instructions. In fact, openMP even has a special directive for this kind of operations.

You will need the `atomic` pragma to make it, well, "atomic":

```
#pragma omp atomic
totalTime += elapsedTime;
```

Note that `atomic` only works when you have a single update to a memory location, like an addition, increment, etc.

If you have a series of instructions that need to atomic together you must use the `critical` directive:

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    // atomic sequence of instructions
}
```

**Edit**: Here's a good suggestion from "snemarch": If you are repeatedly updating the global variable `totalTime` in a parallel loop you can consider using the `reduction` clause to automatize the process and also make it much more efficient:

```
double totalTime = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:totalTime)
for(...)
{
    ...
    totalTime += elapsedTime;
}
```

At the end `totalTime` will correctly contain the sum of the local `elapsedTime` values without need for explicit synchronization.

Comment: I wonder how OpenMP supports atomic adds for floating-point data types on x86 - there's no native instruction for it. Critical sections?

Comment: @snemarch: I couldn't find anything definitive about it, so I guess it uses locks.

Comment: Btw, the compiler doesn't recognise the keyword atomic. g++ ignores it and Intel compiler gives an error. I decided to use omp critical instead.

Comment: Very strange... what message are you getting?

Comment: keep in mind that critical sections are slow - depending on the rest of your code, it might be worth investigating if you can work with per-thread variables and then combining those results once the threads are done. No idea how to express that with OMP, though :)

Comment: @snemarch: It's called `reduce` and there is a clause for that. Good idea actually, I'm gonna write an example.

Comment: Does "reduction" really provides synchronization for a global variable ?